# SPy error: "Axes don't match array" when calling .open_memmap()

Tags: python, numpy, spectral-python

I have some `.bsq` files with corresponding header files (`.hdr`). I want to open and edit them in Python, using the `spectral` ([SPy](https://www.spectralpython.net/)) module.

Since I need to edit the files from within a Python Toolbox in ArcMap (that is, a single Python script which uses the Python installation that comes with ArcMap), I decided to copy the [GitHub repository of the SPy module](https://github.com/spectralpython/spectral) and import it as

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/module")
import spatial as spy
```

in order to be able to run the toolbox on any computer without having to install pip or other software. (I intend to just copy the Toolbox and the module folder, or, in a later step, create a single Python script comprising the Toolbox as well as the SPy-module code.)

I opened some `.bsq`-file and tried to subsequently edit it as `memmap`, following [this example](https://www.spectralpython.net/class_func_ref.html#envi-create-image).

First, I opened the image as `spectral.io.bsqfile.BsqFile`:

```
path = "/path/to/image_header.hdr"
img = spy.open_image(path)
```

I am able to apply various methods to `img` (such as: view metadata, read bands as array, etc), hence, I assume there were no issues with the path or the image file. I can also read single bands with `memmap = True`:

```
mem_band = img.read_band(0, use_memmap = True)
```

Reading a single band results in an array of shape `(lines, samples)` with `dtype: float64` and where lines and sample correspond to the respective values in the `.hdr` file.

However, trying to apply the `.open_memmap()` method to the `BsqFile` instance as follows:

```
mem = img.open_memmap(writable = True)
```

results in the following error:

```
Runtime error
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File
"/path/to/module/spectral/io/spyfile.py", line 809, in open_memmap dst_inter))
 File "/path/to/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 536, in transpose
    return _wrapit(a, 'transpose', axes)
 File "/path/to/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 45, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asattr(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Is this due to some incompatibilities between the `numpy` version that comes with the ArcMap-Python-Installation which I am required to use (numpy version 1.9.2)? Or are there other issues with the code or set-up?

- Python version: 2.7.10
- numpy version: 1.9.2
- spectral version: 0.23.1

**Edit**

With the given Python version, `spectral.envi.create_image()` cannot create images of the given size due to an `OverflowError`. Potentially, this older Python version does not handle large numbers "correctly"?

Using another Python installation, the `.open_memmap()` method worked without issues.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question because it looks like you successfully used `open_memmap`, then you state you received an error. Can you include the command you executed along with the error message?

Comment: @bogatron The error occurred when using ```open_memmap```. I edited the post and hope it is more clear now

Comment: What is `img.shape`?

Comment: @bogatron ```img.shape``` gives ```(3805, 3940, 493)``` (the product of these is, by the way, larger than ```sys.maxint``` which results in an ```OverflowError``` when trying to use ```envi.create_image()``` from ```spectral``` for an image of these dimensions. Maybe the error is related to image size?)

Comment: You heard that python2 was [sunsetted](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2) three years ago, right? On 2020-01-01?

Comment: @J_H I am aware of that. However, I am supposed to work with some ArcMap installation which comes with a Python installation that cannot be upgraded independently from ArcMap.